# ASP.NET MVC Dynamic Action with Hyphens

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project.  I need to be able to map a route such as this:

http://www.mysite.com/Products/Tennis-Shoes

Where the "Action" part of the URL (Tennis-Shoes") could be one of a list of possibilities. I do not want to have to create a separate Action method in my controller for each. I want to map them all to one Action method and I will handle the View that is displayed from there.

I have this working fine by adding a route mapping. However, there are some "Actions" that will need to have a hyphen in them.  ASP.NET MVC routing is trying to parse that hyphen before I can send it to my action.  I have tried to create my own custom Route Handler, but it's never even called.  Once I had a hyphen, all routes are ignored, even my custom one.

Any suggestions? Details about the hyphen situation? Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the URL and reading your description, `Tennis-Shoes` in your example doesn't sound like it should be an action, but a Route parameter. Let's say we have the following controller

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(string product)
    {
        // do something interesting based on product...

        return View(product);
    }
}
```

The `Details` action is going to handle any URLs along the lines of

```
http://www.mysite.com/Products/{product}
```

using the following route

```
routes.MapRoute(
   null,
   "Products/{product}",
   new
   {
       controller = "Products", 
       action = "Details"
   });
```

You might decide to use a different View based on the `product` string, but this is just a basic example.

Comment: That is the route map I'm using right now. I used incorrect terminology. However, the main issue still exists. This route does not work if {product} has a hyphen. How do I resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: do you have any route constraints  on `{product}`? It should work without any constraints.

Comment: No, no route constraints at all. If I remove the hyphen, it works fine. With a hyphen, doesn't route and I get a resource not found error.

Comment: You must make sure that this route appears above any more general routes. Route matching does not look for best match, but stops at first match so order is important. I just tried the above in a new MVC4 application and it works fine so it must be something else in your application.

Comment: +1 for "Tennis-Shoes in your example doesn't sound like it should be an action, but a Route parameter"